# The meaning of running an instance during an online search

Tags: terminology

What does "[Searx ... lets anyone run their own instance](https://medium.com/@stewofkc/which-search-engine-is-best-for-privacy-704f4f80c0af)" mean? Based on my search "an instance is a single copy of the software running on a single physical or virtual server. If you run two copies of the software on the same physical or virtual server, that counts as two instances." So does that mean one can run copies of a software while searching using Searx? If so, what does it mean exactly? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The key words here are **your own** - unlike a regular Internet search engine like Google or DuckDuckGo, where you visit a website and access the instance Google hosts on their own server, you are allowed to download and install Searx on your own computer, or on a server you own. The *instance*, in that case, is the copy of Searx you're running.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanations!